# Создание макета онлайн

Tags: html, css, шаблоны, веб-дизайн

Дизайнеры, поделитесь секретом создания макетов для сайта. Можно ли рисовать вот такие макетики онлайн.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/)